# Disable Informational logging in mongodb

Tags: windows, mongodb, logging

I have mongodb on windows so there is no logrotate or anything. The log consumes 175GB per week! I need to cut this down a lot..

Currently db.GetProfilingLevel() returns 0 and db.getLogComponents() returns -1 for all components and still I get almost 2000 of these bad boys a minute:

`2018-06-25T15:44:59.653+0200 I COMMAND  [conn2355] command mydb.LimitStubs command: find { find: "LimitStubs", filter: { Limit: "asdl;" }, skip: 0, noCursorTimeout: false } planSummary: IXSCAN { Limit: 1, Holder: 1 } keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 nreturned:0 reslen:129 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 0ms`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at [`db.setLogLevel()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setLogLevel/)?

Comment: Yes, it's set to 0. But Informational log messages still get logged. On average I have 300kb of log messages per second! it's simply absurd.